# How can I create a Network class in swift that will handle all my database firestore operations & can be called from any view controller?

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I'm creating an event/venue management app & I want to create a Networking layer to interact with my firestore with various operations so as to reduce the amount of code & redundancy in my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into Singleton design pattern to have shared instance for these operations. You would define it like so:

```
class Firestore {
  static let shared = Firestore()

  func loadEvents() -> [Event] {
   ....
  }
}
```

And usage:

```
Firestore.shared.loadEvents()
```

However be careful with Singletons as they can quickly become “solution” to every problem you will encounter... In this case I think it can be a good option.

Comment: Do I need to name the class Firestore ??

Comment: No, the name does not matter. I used it just as an example, however naming instances as shared, standard or current is naming convention in iOS